# how do i get phone platform details?

Tags: android, java-me

well im making an app and it needs to know on what its running.
lets say i run it on an android phone.
first is there somewhere on in phone that says "android"? 
i need things things like screen size and if it can get touch, supported file types, jsr`s installed.
is there a way to get that info from a phone?
or am i doomed to try and make the mother of all phone databases?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a web page? I noticed that you've tagged the question "java-me", I'm 99% sure java-me is not supported on android.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running on an android phone presumably you'll have written it for android already, so you'll already know.  As you're talking about JSRs and tagged the question "java-me" I assume you actually mean Java ME, and have become confused about whether a Java ME app will just work on Android (it won't, unless you do something like [this](http://microemu.blogspot.com/2008/11/running-java-me-applications-on-android.html).

On Java ME, you can do all these things.

Screen size:  create a Canvas and call getWidth()/getHeight()

Handset name:  call `System.getProperty("microedition.platform");`

JSR support, try instantiating a class from the JSR by using `Class.forName()` -- if it throws `ClassNotFoundException`, the JSR is not supported.

Comment: well the point is to make a simple code that works on "every" phone
using java 1.2 or 1.3 as far as i know its the lowest common denominator so it should work on most phones...